# Scrape Images, Links and Texts serially using Goutte

Tags: php, laravel-5, goutte

I've the bellow code trying to take the `html` elements 1 by 1 serially include the tag it self without any `styles` and `classes`. Plus, i'm failing to get `images`

```
    $client = new Client();

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm');

    $crawler->filter('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, p > img, div > img, p > a')->each(function(Crawler $node, $i){
        if ($node->filter('p')){
            echo $node->text()."<br/>";

        } else if ($node->filter('pre')) {
            echo '<code>'.$node->html().'</code><br/>';
        }
    });
```

But whatever I do, I'm either getting only texts when i use `$node->text()` or all html in that page when i use `$node->html()` in that page.

I'm trying to get for example `p` - `<p>Text Here</p>`.  `img` - `<img src="default.jp"/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `$node->filter('p')` will always return true, since the returned value of the function `filter` is a `Crawler` object, so the second `else if` never called.
If you want to check if a crawler has nodes in it you can use the `count()` function.

As for your code - I'm not so sure **why** this is what you are doing, but basically what your code does is check if the current element HAS a `<p>` child element (is that what you are trying to do?), and if it has - print the content of the parent's node text.

In order to get the nodes DOMElement from the Crawler (`$node`) you can use

```
$node->getNode(0)`
```

and using this node you can check the `nodeName` (==tag name), get the `textContent` (the content of the tag), etc.

Here is an example you can use:

```
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm');

$crawler->filter('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, pre, p > img, div > img, p > a')->each(function(Crawler  $node, $i){
    if (in_array($node->getNode(0)->nodeName, ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'p', 'a'])) {
        echo "{$node->getNode(0)->nodeName} => {$node->getNode(0)->textContent}.<br/>\n";
    } elseif ($node->getNode(0)->nodeName == 'pre') {
        echo "pre => <code>".$node->html()."</code><br/>\n";
    } elseif ($node->getNode(0)->nodeName == 'img') {
        echo 'img => src="'.$node->getNode(0)->getAttribute('src')."\" <br/>\n";
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. It really helped a lot. But i still have an issue in case of links and images. How can i get the links and src this way for example if the page i'm scraping is `example.com` and has an image - `<img href="default.jpg">` ->  `img => src=http://example.com/default.jpg`

Comment: You can combine the `$domain` and the `$node->getNode(0)->getAttribute('src')`, however note that you might need to check several things (like directory structure/traversing).

Comment: I found a solution for that here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573193/3866364 .  Anyway, thanks for the answer.  :)

Comment: Great :) this is specifically for the path.